# Could not open '/tunables/proc'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, app-armor

Jumped from Ubuntu 14.04 to 19.04, everything was a-ok until I started getting error messages stating that it could not open 'tunables/proc' on line 17 of 'tunables/global/':

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "core" (7917) security profiles (cannot setup apparmor for snap "core": cannot create host snap-confine apparmor configuration: cannot reload snap-confine apparmor profile: cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.7917 in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
)
- Setup snap "core" (7917) security profiles (cannot create host snap-confine apparmor configuration: cannot reload snap-confine apparmor profile: cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.core.7917 in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
)
```

and

```
docker: Error response from daemon: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: running `/usr/sbin/apparmor_parser apparmor_parser -Kr /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default031282080` failed with output: AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default031282080 in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'

error: exit status 1.
```

I've been following various rabbit holes on quirky apparmor issues surrounding 'tunables/proc' and 'tunables/global'. I've triend reinstalling, a new fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, manually copying files from the [apparmor source files](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/apparmor/2.10.95-0ubuntu2.10/apparmor_2.10.95.orig.tar.gz) to the respective directories on the system.

I'm at a loss. How can I fix this?

Systemctl AppArmor Status:

```
● apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-10-24 11:41:59 UTC; 31min ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
 Main PID: 1669 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/nvidia_modprobe in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula apparmor.systemd[1669]: Error: At least one profile failed to load
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 11:41:59 caligula systemd[1]: Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
ubuntu@caligula:~/apparmor-2.10.95/profiles$
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393628/docker-error-response-from-daemon-apparmor-enabled-on-system-but-the-docker-de/58866095#58866095

Answer (score 5):

This just happened to me when moving an encrypted system to a new SSD with higher storage capacity. `rsync` seems to have missed it :(

I solved it by creating the file that cannot be found:
`/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/proc`

With the default contents (found in a old file in /proc while searching for the tunables folder funny enough):

```
#    Copyright (C) 2012 Canonical Ltd.
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of version 2 of the GNU General Public
#    License published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

# @{PROC} is the location where proc is mounted.
@{PROC}=/proc/
```

So for the linux newbies the commands:

```
cd /etc/apparmor.d/tunables
sudo nano proc
```

Then copy paste the default value and press `control + x` then `y` and then enter to save it.

Comment: Thanks, that probably saved me hours of research!

Comment: Strangely, I had this exact problem for the exact same reason.  Not sure why rsync is skipping this file.